# Is there a concept of "rotor is blocked" feedback in a stepper motor?

Tags: stepper-motor, feedback, stepper-driver

I am building a mechanism to move a lever via a stepper motor controlled by a Raspberry Pi (following this [tutorial](https://makersportal.com/blog/raspberry-pi-stepper-motor-control-with-nema-17)) and I will be using a [Stepperonline HS1715](https://www.omc-stepperonline.com/download/17HS15-1504S-X1.pdf) motor.

I can estimate the angle I will have to turn the motor but it would be better to have a feedback system that would inform me that the lever is completely pulled and that the motor cannot turn anymore.

- Is something like this available at all in such systems?

  - if yes: what is the signal I should monitor on the GPIOs?
  - if no: is this a normal behaviour for the motor to have its rotor blocked (and therefore there is nothing to do) or does it put the motor at risk (in which case I will have to rely on my calculations of the angle)

Comment: Sounds like you need some form of absolute position sensor or limit switches. Even without the issue of losing steps, it seems you require some form of feedback.  You might want to reconsider if a stepper motor is the right choice for your application. A pm motor might be more suitable - smaller, better torque characteristics etc. It depends on your application.

Comment: @Kartman, typo there on 'losing steps'. 'Loosing steps' sounds like you're setting steps free :-)

Comment: @Kartman: this motor will be pulling down a standard door handle (through a cable), it will need to make several rotations for one movement and I took a stepper motor because I wanted to set the number of rotations (to stop when the handle is down). My idea of a pm motor is that it turns until there is electrical tension applied. If there are motors that would not go further when blocked then it would be ideal.

Comment: Well couldn't this be "set" simply by limiting the motor current?  To a value where the motor can't spin the door handle past it's normal stops.  If that is normally 1200 steps, then drive it 1300 in each direction with current limiting.

Comment: @WoJ attach a flag to the cable ... sense the position of the flag

Comment: Common techniques for this sort of application might be a torque limiting clutch which could be as simple as a gear mounted on a spring loaded lever. The torque causes the gear to skip teeth based on the force applied by the spring. Using a om motor this would only requiring the power applied for a given time to tension/untension the cable. You could use steppers but there are downsides as Tim describes in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Modern stepper motor driver chips, e.g. from Trinamic, offer this as an option: they detect missed steps based on the winding voltage and current. It's often used as a virtual end-stop: there's a mechanical end stop, but without a switch, and the driver's features are used to detect when the motor stops turning, presumably after hitting the stop.

Answer (score -1):

> Is there a concept of "rotor is blocked" feedback in a stepper motor?

Concept, yes.  Practical reality -- not really.  In theory you could sense the back-EMF of the motor and tell if it's turning, but in practice you'd never get it reliable.

> is this a normal behaviour for the motor to have its rotor blocked (and therefore there is nothing to do)

If you drive the motor within its published limits and you build the mechanism to match, then it can be stalled all day without a problem.  In fact, one cheap and reliable way to position a stepper where you want it is to drive it toward a stop with more steps than it has range -- that way you know it's against the stop when you're done.

If you have a big noisy stepper this will be irritating and possibly alarming to nearby humans, it's wasteful of power, and you have to make sure the mechanism is stout enough to handle you doing that all the time.  I've only seen it done routinely on automotive gauges with a super-light mechanism and a super-small motor.  Usual practice is to build a limit switch into your mechanism, wired to a GPIO to tell you the mechanism is in the home position.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get the concept-vs-reality point or see how it'd help learners...reads like wordplay, to be honest. Downvoting for that reason.

Comment: The OP said "concept".  A 100% "honest", but totally misleading answer, is an unadorned, 100% unhelpful, "yes".